# How to make function in application_controller.rb visible in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application-controller.rb I did:

```
def show_footer?
   @show_footer = true
end
```

Then in my view I am getting an error saying show_footer? isn't defined.

note, this view is in another controller then inherits application_controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in `application_helper.rb` instead.

Also, you probably mean to have `@show_footer == true` instead of `=`.

Comment: well I think I meant @show_footer = true and then in other controllers I want to make @show_footer to false, make sense?

Comment: Typically, a method with a question mark at the end returns true or false and is not used to set the value. For example, Array.empty? doesn't make the array empty, it just lets you know if it is empty.

Answer (score 5):

Controller methods are not in scope to views; only helper methods are. You can add a controller method as a helper also by doing the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :show_footer?

  def show_footer?
    # Your method implementation.
  end
end
```

Now you'll be able to refer to `show_footer?` in *both* your controllers and your views.